# Less Compiling Doesn't work for me in Netbeans 8.1 beta

Tags: netbeans, less, netbeans-8.1

I want to start using the option to compile my less files from within an html5 project in netbeans 8.1 (Windows 7).  However it doesn't work for me.

1 . I npm installed less from the command line with -g option flag.

2. I opened up the tools...options...html/js menu and placed the path in the less path input box. I hit apply and then ok.
3. I made a change to my less file and hit the run button and it shows that it compiled in the output dialog box.

Message shown:

> "C:\Users\Larry\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd" "--source-map"
>   "--source-map-rootpath=../less" "--source-map-url=style.css.map"
>   "C:\Users\Larry\Desktop\interface\public_html\less\style.less"
>   "C:\Users\Larry\Desktop\interface\public_html\css\style.css" Done.

I have tried exiting netbeans and then loading it back up but it will still not work.  I have even tried loading a new project with a different less file and it still doesn't work.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: No problem , I am glad I could help, sorry about the syntax error I placed it in the wrong spot.  You know how quick people are to downvote I didn't get a chance to edit.

Comment: I know you needed help with your code not with learning his design philosophy. Take care and good luck with your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have been something with the beta release of Netbeans 8.1.  I downloaded and installed the production release of Netbeans 8.1.  I then had to re add the path to the lessc.cmd file as described in step 2 of my question(step below).

> I opened up the tools...options...html/js menu and placed the path in
>   the less path input box. I hit apply and then ok.

I then placed my less file with the same name as my css file in a folder named less in the root directory of my project. Now when I save or run my project the changes are reflected in my css file.

Note: Make sure you have a folder named css and less in your projects root directory and place the respective css and less files with the same name in the appropriate folders.

Example:

```
     MyProject(root directory folder)

      |                          |

less(Folder)                css(Folder)

     |                           |

style.less                   style.css
```